# FILE upload using angularjs without plugin

Tags: angularjs

How to upload a image file using angular without a plugin....?
I have tried many code shown in GitHub but all things are using a plugin so give me a perfect code

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend you take a look at those links :https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Upload and Download File with AngularJS -- [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/uSsHVmsKv82Ng2baKxGJ?p=preview).